# Identity framework. GetUser(id) not load IdentityUserRole

Tags: asp.net, identity

I have

```
UserManager<MyUser> myUserManager;
```

After I use `MyUser user = myUserManager.GetUser(id);`

`user.Roles` is null. How can I get `user.Roles` ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because lazy loading is enabled in your database context. This means that any associated objects will not be loaded when you query the user table (e.g., Roles).

You can turn on eager loading by changing the configuration of your context: context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; but it's not really recommended due to additional trips to the database.

Enabling lazy loading, you should override the method in a custom UserManager class and use the "Include" method in your query.

See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/788559/Loading-Related-Entities-with-Entity-Framework-A-B

Comment: sorry but I don't know how to modify the dbcontext of asp.net identity framework.